# Group objects based on attribute value in Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a list of loan objects with attributes loanamount and duedate, I would like to group these objects based on loanamount and count number of EMI's based on amount.

As of now I am doing this with the help of iterator by iterating and comparing each object in the list. What would be the better way to achieve this?

**Example :**

```
class Loan{
BigDecimal loanamount;
Date duedate;
----getters and setters
}

class Test
{
void sortLoan()
{
Loan loan1=new Loan();
loan1.setLoanamount(100);
loan1.setDuedate(new Date()); //Jan

Loan loan2=new Loan();
loan2.setLoanamount(100);
loan2.setDuedate(new Date()); //Feb

Loan loan3=new Loan();
loan3.setLoanamount(200);
loan3.setDuedate(new Date()); //Mar

Loan loan4=new Loan();
loan4.setLoanamount(200);
loan4.setDuedate(new Date()); //Apr

Loan loan5=new Loan();
loan5.setLoanamount(200);
loan5.setDuedate(new Date()); //May

Loan loan6=new Loan();
loan6.setLoanamount(100);
loan6.setDuedate(new Date()); //June

Loan loan7=new Loan();
loan7.setLoanamount(100);
loan7.setDuedate(new Date()); //July

List<Loan> loanList=new ArrayList<>();
loanList.add(loan1);
loanList.add(loan2);
loanList.add(loan3);
loanList.add(loan4);
loanList.add(loan5);
loanList.add(loan6);
loanList.add(loan7);

}

Expected output : Loan amount of $100 for 1st 2 months
                  Loan amount of $200 for next 3 months
                  Loan amount of $100 for next 2 months
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check `Enumerable.GroupBy()` method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 then you can use below code :-

Map< BigDecimal, List> loanListGroup =
    loanList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.loanamount));

Give it a try and let me know if it works.

This one is working in my system , Let me know if its working for you..

Map> loanListGroup = loanList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.loanamount));

Comment: This works partially as it groups all items based on loanamount, but in my case it should consider position/date as well. In the example I explained above, the object loan6 & loan7 are of amount 100 but needs to be grouped separately than of loan1 and loan2 objects. Thank you.

Comment: @springbatcher Please use this one Map<Object,Map<Date,List<Loan>>> loanListGroup = loanList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.loanamount,
     Collectors.groupingBy(Loan::getDuedate)));

Comment: thank you. This also works as earlier only grouping all 100's in a group and 200's in another group. But what I am looking for is 3 groups, like first 2 100's in one group, then 3 200's in another group and last 2 100's in one group. Can this be achieved with java 8 Streams?